# function returns undefined when I want to find documents from dababase in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

As I said, I want to create a function that have to arguments, username and email. If one of them is in the database, then user can't register.

```
function checkAll(username, email) {
  let num = 0;
  User.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     if (username === result[i].username || email === result[i].email) {
        num++;
      }
    }
    db.close();
    if (num == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}

console.log(checkAll("test", "test@test.com"));
```

I know that `User.find()` is an asynchronous function that have a second arguments that it is a callback, but my question is: **Why does it return undefined??**

Comment: Because it's an asynchronous function and you can't return like that from an asynchronous function

Answer (score 0):

The function `checkAll` finishes execution before the callback of the `find` operation is triggered, and since you aren't returning anything from checkAll, `undefined` is logged.

This should make it clearer :

```
function checkAll(username, email) {
  let num = 0;
  User.find({}, (err, result) => {
    console.log('here');
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     if (username === result[i].username || email === result[i].email) {
        num++;
      }
    }
    db.close();
    if (num == 0) {
    console.log('now here');
      return true;
    }
    console.log('or mebbe here');
    return false;
  });
}

console.log(checkAll("test", "test@test.com"));
```

you will see `undefined` and then `here` and then `now here` OR `or mebbe here`

Answer (score 0):

Your outer function `checkAll` returns `undefined` since it has no return statement. Only your inner function, the callback to your mongo query does. Because of the async nature of the query, you can't simply return true or false. Your options are basically thus:

**Pass a callback (or two) to `checkAll`:**

```
function checkAll(username, email, cb){ //...
function checkAll(username, email, cb_success, cb_fail){ //...
```

Where you call `cb` with `true` or false from within your query callback, sending execution back to the original callsite.

**Use a promise:**

```
function checkAll(username, email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        User.find({$or: [{username}, {emai}]}, (err, result)=>{
            if(result) reject('User exists');
            else resolve('Username/ email free');
        });
    };
}

// Usage:
checkAll('alice', 'test@example.com').then(create_user, user_exists);
```

Where `create_user` is a function handles the success case and `user_exists` is a function that handles the failure case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked well.

Comment: great! if this is the solution you're going with, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)